# jQuery blur fires for each row of input text in a table

Tags: jquery, generics, blur

I have an issue with a generic event handler for jQuery blur, I have a page that dynamically can add rows of input text to capture data, one of the requirements is to save data after each input box just in case something should happen and be able to continue with all the data entered.

The code fires and the data is entered or updated in the DB, but it will send it for as many times as there are rows and seeing the events are in different threads, it data is not accurate.

```js
$("#detectors tbody input[type=text]").blur(function(e) {
  var elementid = $(this);
  var j = elementid.attr("id");
  if (j != "addNewDet") {
    var eledId = j.slice(-1);
    var eidD = "";
    if (!isNaN(eledId)) {
      eidD = parseInt(j.slice(-1));
    }
    //var q = elementid.id.val();
    var dsn = "#det_serialnumber" + eidD;
    var dmi = "#det_ptMdId" + eidD;
    var dmp = "#det_mdpartno" + eidD;
    var dc = "#det_Coil" + eidD;
    var dcp = "#det_casephase" + eidD;
    var id = tid;
    var ptmdid = $(dmi).val();
    var part = $(dmp).val();
    var ccoil = $(dc).val();
    var sn = $(dsn).val();
    var casep = $(dcp).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/Home/InsertIntoDB",
      data: {
        mdid: ptmdid,
        partno: part,
        coil: ccoil,
        serialnumber: sn,
        casephase: casep
      },
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        var resp = data[0];
        $(dmi).val(resp.ptMdId);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="detectors">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Serial number</th>
      <th>MD part #</th>
      <th>Coil</th>
      <th>Case phase</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_serialnumber1" name="det.serialnumber" type="text" value="" />
        <input name="det.ptMdId" class="text-box single-line" id="det_ptMdId1" type="hidden" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_mdpartno1" name="det.mdpartno" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_Coil1" name="det.Coil" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_casephase1" name="det.casephase" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_serialnumber2" name="det.serialnumber" type="text" value="" />
        <input name="det.ptMdId" class="text-box single-line" id="det_ptMdId2" type="hidden" value="0">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_mdpartno2" name="det.mdpartno" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_Coil2" name="det.Coil" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="det_casephase2" name="det.casephase" type="text" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: the problem is if I enter data in the first row of text boxes they get added updated properly, but if I add a row and enter the data the data is sent like this (excuse the json) 
 [{"mdpartno":"9998","Coil":"1/4 Tubing","serialnumber":"Test #12","casephase":"None","ptTestId":1362,"ptMdId":1381,"testnumber":"2406"},
 {"mdpartno":"9998","Coil":"1/4 Tubing","serialnumber":"Test #20","casephase":"None","ptTestId":1362,"ptMdId":1383,"testnumber":"2406"}]

Comment: Well as we type it should be like this: first input [{"mdpartno":"","Coil":"","serialnumber":"Test #12","casephase":"","ptMdId":,"testnumber":"2406"}  then the second [{"mdpartno":"9998","Coil":"","serialnumber":"Test #12","casephase":"","ptMdId":,"testnumber":"2406"} and so on for the first row and then after the first input on secound row   [{"mdpartno":"","Coil":"","serialnumber":"Test #20","casephase":"","ptMdId":,"testnumber":"2406"} and the second  [{"mdpartno":"9999","Coil":"","serialnumber":"Test #20","casephase":"","ptMdId":,"testnumber":"2406"} it sends data for both rows on the 2nd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code to create separate event handlers for each row, I could not find another solution for this, in my code I added the blur event options including the ajax call in a variable and I initialize the event at the same time I add the row dynamically: dmi will hold the added element id,

```
var blurOption = {
  url: "/Home/InsertIntoDB",
  data: {
    mdid: ptmdid,
    partno: part,
    coil: ccoil,
    serialnumber: sn,
    casephase: casep
  },
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {
    var resp = data[0];
    $(dmi).val(resp.ptMdId);
  }
```

after the row is added

```
$(dmi).blur(blurOption);
```